# thread synchronization - synchronous block

Tags: java, multithreading, session, thread-safety

my code,

```
    synchronized (countInfo) {
        count++;
        countInfo = new File(dto.findMyLocation()+"\\Properties\\countInfo"+Start.session.getId()+".txt");
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(countInfo));
        writer.write(String.valueOf(count));
        writer.close();
        }
```

here countInfo is reference to a file and the method in which this piece of code is written my multiple threads. i am getting a null pointer exception at the "synchronized (countInfo)" line. i know this is because at this line it is not yet known wat countInfo is initialized to, so for this i will have to move the 
`

```
countInfo = new File(dto.findMyLocation()+"\\Properties\\countInfo"+Start.session.getId()+".txt");
```

line outside of the synchronous block. but if i do that , then all the threads accessing this method of mine will crate a new file. But my goal is only one of the threads (the first thread to come into this method ) has to create a file and all other threads should just read the info in the created file. How can i achieve this?? Please help.  I am new to java and Multi Threading! please enrich my knowledge!! thanks in advance!

**UPDATE** - an image that explains the flow. 
[image: over all flow dipiction]

the lines marked in YELLOW, cross session file access will never happen as i have used the session ID appended to the file name.

Comment: surprisingly!! after i moved that line out of the sync block to above. its working fine!! but how!!!!!!!!!??? and by the way after i remove the sync block and the entire concept of thread synchronization also, its working fine for me!! how can this be possible?? i am seeinga complete difference on wat research i have done and wat i am seeing practically here!! can some one please explain me thsi!!??

Comment: Wait, you synchronize on an object which you _reassign_ in the synchronized block??

Comment: @VasanthNagKV But will it be thread-safe?

Comment: @VasanthNagKV it works sometime doesn't mean it will always work. So to provide guarantee you can not skip synchronization.

Comment: Tell me about the session id ... different processes/users can have different ids? ... so you want to write to the file for the particular sessions?

Comment: Why do you think each thread will create a file? Only if the files are named differently, right? Don't you want the session ids in the file name (looks like your code specifies that).

Comment: hi xagyg.. yeah, different users have different session ids and i want that user to deal with only his file, and that is the reason i have included this sessionID naming of the file. and yeah you are rite. each thread will not create different file. one thread will create it and other threads will pick the same file, i later realized this fact :).
and @vipin - i have tried so many times and it seems to be 100% thread safe without the sync block too!! i am still surprised!!

Comment: @VasanthNagKV Without seeing your code we cant say why it is thread safe or looks like thread safe :) . For example few days back i was resolving thread and memory issue in one old web application and it had some serious issues which were never cought in last 5 years , but still i have to modify code to make that thred safe.

Comment: OH!! okay okay. anyways, please tell me, the code i have posted here is proper now?? i have moved the countInfo line where the file is created to outside. above the sync block. is it all fine now?

Answer (score 1):

It will help you if you read a bit about threadsafe singlton or doublecheck locking mechanism.
For you scenario you can do something like this (may be for clear code seprate the logic for file creation and data writing):

```
    //make countinfo volatile
    public volatile File countInfo = null;
    .
    .
    public void writeIntoFile(){
            countInfo = getFile();
            synchronized (countInfo) {
                count++;
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(countInfo));
                writer.write(String.valueOf(count));
                writer.close();
            }
        }

        public File getFile(){
            if(countInfo==null){
                synchronized (this){
                    if(countInfo==null){
                        countInfo = new File(dto.findMyLocation()+"\\Properties\\countInfo"+Start.session.getId()+".txt");    
                    }
                }
            }
            return countInfo;
        }
```

Comment: HI mark, actually, let me explain the entire flow, i have a threadpool with 100 threads assume, and each of this 100 threads is calling a function X() and this X() has the code that i have posted. so with the explanationaand example given above, i googled out for what a volatile word is and understood that u are trying to tell me, that when a thread tries to accure a lock in the file countInfo, it will update the recent changes and then take a lock on it eh?? i found this 'update and then taking lock' concept here -http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-volatile-keyword-0

Comment: @VasanthNagKV As you gave your requirement in other answer of mine , this will be perfect answer to your problem. For more details read Effective java - Item 71.

Comment: @vipin, so what i have understood is correct?? i mean the thing that i have commented above your comment in reply to Mark, is that correctly understood by me? so that i can start implementing this in my project. please help.

Comment: @VasanthNagKV from your comment its clear you are newbie to java :) , and I would suggest iplement answer this in your project.

Comment: @vipin, Bull's eye!! :) yes i am a newbie to java. i would like to understand the concept and then put it into the code. so please tell me have i understood it correctly?? :)

Comment: Your understanding is correct but not complete. You are flying a plane with manual :) ( Goggling something and trying to implement it on the fly). Please don't take my comment otherwise but in longer run you will same much time if you spend sometime now to go through some book like effective java or brain gotz concurrency etc. Otherwise you might get into very time consuming bugs in code.

Comment: @MAK, ha ha, thanks for your advice. but i am just learning all these practically, that is all, i am trying to develop and simple web scrapping application for one of the clients. and i am at the end of the development and i wanted to be sure, so came up here. what i feel is the best way is to dive into the pool straight away and then the art of swimming will automatically catch up when i struggle. :) :) anyways!! thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: @Mak - i think this code is not fine. Forgive me if am wrong. here in the get file method, you are telling like, if countInfo is != null, entre the if block. here in my case this variable will always be null for the first time and i am initializing inside that get file method. but in the code you have out that != null case, how will the control enter the if block and actually create the file??

Comment: @VasanthNagKV My Bad, My thought process was not thread safe resulting corrupted answer. I have been thinking about some other question while writing this answer so messed up with condition otherwise logic and approach is still valid. Apologies :(

Comment: @Mak, no problem :), i used the approach to make the method only Synchronized instead of using the synch block, will this still work for me after my modification??